# How should develop an environment that non-programmer can extract data as relational DB from JSON formatted?

Tags: python, sql, json, mariadb

My problem was that json data stored into maria DB was encoded into JSON-encoded (unicode escaped(ascii code)!?. A part of the text was changed into "\u????").

So, on phase extraction from json data, the text data should be encoded into UTF8. I try to create view table formed relational database and enable to export for non-programmer to get the view using phpMyAdmin, but the problem failed encoding from json-encoded to utf8. The SQL command was below.

```sql
select convert(json_extract(json_col, '$.text') using utf8) as text from json_table;
```

I stored json data including emoji into maria DB(v10.3.21) via python(v3.8)+sqlalchemy. The json data(utf8) was encoded into json-encoded via sqlalchemy json type implicitly.

I want to teach me.

1. [I hope] Can I  solve this encoding problem only side maria DB / phpMyAdmin to create a view solved unicode escape.

   - If charcode of the column of json-data is changed into `latin1` for exclude unicode escape, the characode will be converted into utf8 automatically by phpMyAdmin or web browser software?
2. Can I correspond by changing code of Python?(No-sqlalchemy? dangerous?)
3. Corresponding inside client program (Sequel Pro)
4. Other

my_json table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_json` (
  `id_` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `json` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_`);
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## sqlalchemy

```
class MyJson(Base):
        __tablename__ = table_name
        __table_args__ = ({"mysql_engine": "InnoDB"})
        id = Column('id', BIGINT(unsigned=True), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
        _json = Column('json', JSON)
```

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?charset=utf8mb4'.format(secret), echo=True, convert_unicode=True, connect_args={"charset": 'utf8mb4', "use_unicode": True})
```

Comment: thought you would need a webfrontend for your non programmer.

Comment: Thank you, I think more.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.

This problem was solved. by only shifted from mariaDB10.3.xx to MySQL5.7.

On mariaDB, json data was stored as type longtext, utf8mb4_bin. However, on MySQL, the json data was stored into type json.

MariaDB table structure could not be changed into type json in as same procedure as in mysql. So I shifted my env to MySQL+Docker, now.